# SQL Server encapsulating packets into IPsec?

Tags: wireshark, sql, ipsec

I found this with Wireshark while troubleshooting a SQL Server AlwaysOn cluster for that damned ASYNC_NETWORK_IO problem: a few packets originating from SQL Server's data port (manually configured as 40443) being encapsulated with IPsec (ESP).

[image]

- I already excluded Windows GPO automatically configuring IPsec
- It's only a few packets with such characteristic (around one for each thousand)

Can anyone shed some light on this weird behavior? Not ASYNC_NETWORK_IO, but the ESP packets generated by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't ESP packets. The Wireshark protocol dissector matches a chunk of the MS SQL request or response which happens to look *kind of* like an ESP header, even though it is on the incorrect port (encapsulated ESP always using port 4500) and the dissected parameters don't quite match up.